# Validation image laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

I am having doubts on a subject.
I have my ratings to run in extensions but still the error recurs image size giving me this error.

> The file "IMG_2580.JPG" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).

I went to the php.ini file and took the comment "extension = php_fileinfo.dll" and was soon running the extensions but the max size 3000 does not.
In short extensions show me the error in size it gives me that error page.
Some help?

```
public static $profileData = array(
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'name' =>  'required|min:5',
        'data_nascimento' => 'date',
        'imagem' => 'image|max:3000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png'
        );
```

Comment: Resolution: if the php.ini and change the upload_max_filesize to 20MB eg max: 3000 already works and shows the error :)
I hope to help someone

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself.

Comment: Hit the button down below that says to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini update the following

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```

**Note :**

1. Restart the xampp (apache) after you change the values
2. Make sure that you change in the correct `php.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution:**

This code remains the same

```
public static $profileData = array(
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'name' =>  'required|min:5',
        'data_nascimento' => 'date',
        'imagem' => 'image|max:3000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png'
        );
```

If the php.ini and change the upload_max_filesize to 20MB the max:3000 already works and shows the error :) I hope to help someone

Comment: Have you restarted your apache server after changing the values ?

Comment: You enabled the above two as i said in my answer ?

Comment: Yes
I had already solved but thanks :)
I will now deal with resize